# C++ const std::string assignment error if the right handside contains concatenation on string literals

Tags: c++, string, compiler-errors, variable-assignment

I am new to C++, I encountered this oddity with const std::string assignment

This works fine:
    const std::string hello = "Hello";
    const std::string message = hello + " world";

This gives compiler error: 
    const std::string message = "Hello" + " world";

I do not understand why this is, anyone ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `operator +` defined that takes two pointers of type `const char*` and returns a new array of characters containing the concatenation of the strings they point to.

What you can do is:

```
std::string message = std::string("Hello") + "world";
```

Or even:

```
std::string message = "Hello" + std::string("world");
```

Comment: To be pedantic, they are not `const char*`, they are `const char[6]` and `const char[7]`.

Comment: @JesseGood: Right, the string literals are arrays, indeed. But when passed as arguments to an operator overload, wouldn't they decay to pointers?

Comment: Yes, the do decay to `const char*` when passed to the overload. I was thinking of the types with `"Hello" + " world"` since there is no overload involved, but reading over what you said again, it is not incorrect (sorry for the noise :)).

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate  literal strings, you don't need to put extra `+` between them, just put them together without any operator will perform the concatenation:

```
std::string message = "Hello" "world";
printf("%s\n", message.c_str());
```

and the above code will give you:

```
Helloworld
```